# laser_frame is pointing upwards

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone ,im very new to ros and found some issue with gmapping recently .my laser scanner is pointing upwards and couldnt able to do gmapping and i want to confirm whether my tf structure is working good or not

```
<robot
  name="archer">
  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.0031521 -0.070703 0.33777"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="238.44" />
      <inertia
        ixx="39.449"
        ixy="-0.18466"
        ixz="-0.28812"
        iyy="16.942"
        iyz="-7.836"
        izz="29.425" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.1098 0.1098 0.1098 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link
    name="Wheel_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 6.9389E-18 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="1.232" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0033433"
        ixy="-8.6429E-19"
        ixz="-7.2476E-19"
        iyy="0.0033433"
        iyz="7.219E-19"
        izz="0.0062939" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/Wheel_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.1098 0.1098 0.1098 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/Wheel_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="RHS"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.2 0.075 -0.01"
      rpy="0 1.57 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="Wheel_2" />
    <axis
      rpy="0 1 0"
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="Wheel_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 6.9389E-18 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="1.232" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0033433"
        ixy="-8.6429E-19"
        ixz="-7.2476E-19"
        iyy="0.0033433"
        iyz="7.219E-19"
        izz="0.0062939" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/Wheel_2.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.1098 0.1098 0.1098 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/Wheel_2.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="LHS"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.2 0.075 -0.01"
      rpy="0 1.57 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="Wheel_1" />
    <axis
      rpy="0 1 0"
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="laser_frame">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.026431 -0.000309 0.0041422"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.32426" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00070878"
        ixy="-1.2652E-06"
        ixz="1.7595E-06"
        iyy="0.00067504"
        iyz="-1.6612E-05"
        izz="0.00056684" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/Lidar.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://archer_desctest/meshes/Lidar.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="lidar_mount"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
      xyz="0 -0.37929 0.64252"
      rpy=" 0.93993 -7.9855E-17 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="laser_frame" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
<gazebo reference="laser_frame">
    <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="head_rplidar_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0.06 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>40</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>720</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-3.14159265</min_angle>
            <max_angle>3.14159265</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.2</min>
          <max>30.0</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_rplidar_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
        <topicName>scan</topicName>
        <frameName>laser_frame</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330689/laser_frame-is-pointing-upwards/) by [kallivalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/42408/kallivalli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're correct there is a small error in your URDF. The confusion is that there are two different coordinate frame conventions used for mobile robots and optical sensors, look at the suffix frames described in [REP 103](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html). Your lidar uses a frame where z points in the direction of the sensor, x is left and y is down. However your robot is defined using standard ROS conventions where z is up, and x faces in the same direction the robot is facing. You'll need to add a rotation to the definition of your `laser_frame` to correct this.

**Update**

You want to update the roll, pitch and yaw values provided in the following tag. I can't tell you which value without knowing more about the structure of your robot, but it will be adding or subtracting `pi / 2` from one of those three values.

```
<joint
    name="lidar_mount"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
      xyz="0 -0.37929 0.64252"
      rpy=" 0.93993 -7.9855E-17 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="laser_frame" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kallivalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/42408/kallivalli/) on 2019-09-17**:
can you tell where to add this in urdf file ?